# Doing something dumb with queryfactory and relationship query

Tags: apex, fflib

I've been using the fflib pattern in salesforce development since before the introduction of the query factory.   I'm having a problem making a simple relationship query work using the queryfactory.   I'm trying to query OrderItem records, and include the Product Family.   Here's an abbreviated version of the OrderItemSelector class, with the selector method and resulting error below.   I must be missing something obvious, any help would be much appreciated!

```
public class OrderItemSelector extends fflib_SObjectSelector
{

   ...

   public List<OrderItem> selectOrderItemsByOrderId(Set<ID> idSet)
   {
       fflib_QueryFactory qf = newQueryFactory();
       new Product2Selector().configureQueryFactoryFields(qf, Product2.Family.getDescribe().getRelationshipName());
       return Database.query(qf.setCondition('OrderId in :idSet').toSOQL());
   }
}
```

fflib_QueryFactory.InvalidFieldException: Invalid field 'null' for object 'OrderItem'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this:

Note that you need to use the `OrderItem.PricebookEntry.Product2` relationship

```
public List<OrderItem> selectOrderItemsByOrderId(Set<ID> idSet) {
   if (idSet.isEmpty() {return new List<OrderItem>();} // avoid burning soql
   fflib_QueryFactory qf = newQueryFactory()
      .setCondition('OrderId IN :idSet');

   new Product2sSelector() // add relationship fields defined in Product2sSelector
     .configureQueryFactoryFields(qf,'PricebookEntry.Product2');

   return Database.query(qf.toSOQL());
}
```

If you don't want to return all the Product2 selector fields and want to limit to a fieldset:

```
new Product2sSelector()
  .configureQueryFactoryFields(qf,
                              'PricebookEntry.Product2',
                               SObjectType.Product2.fieldsets.MyFieldSet);
```

If you only care about a few fields on Product2 unique to this selector method:

```
public List<OrderItem> selectOrderItemsByOrderId(Set<ID> idSet) {
   if (idSet.isEmpty() {return new List<OrderItem>();} // avoid burning soql
   fflib_QueryFactory qf = newQueryFactory()
      .selectFields(new List<String> {
         'PricebookEntry.Product2.Family',
         'PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductCode'})
      .setCondition('OrderId IN :idSet');

   return Database.query(qf.toSOQL());
}
```

Comment: Cropredy, huge thanks, this got me rolling again, and is as clean/elegant as I knew it should be.   I especially like the isEmpty check on idSet, and will make it a regular part of the pattern.

Comment: @Woody - feel free to post additional fflib (including apexmocks) questions on stackexchange - I'm happy to help - just be sure to put fflib in the subject and tag so I'll see it.

Comment: I try to be a low maintenance type, but will take you up on that when truly stumped!

Comment: @woody - another resource, my [apexmocks blog posts (4 and counting)](http://cropredysfdc.com/2017/10/11/apex-mocks-and-enterprise-patterns-first-in-a-series/)